# Limitation of dog as pets

Tags: halal-haram, dogs

Aslam alaikum!
My question is whether I can keep a dog as a pet at home and not allow him to enter a certain area where I will be praying my Salah?
I really want a dog as a pet at home. That is why am asking this question. Even tho I know about the notes about a dog being haram. But was wondering if it could be possible this way?

Answer (score -3):

Dog is not haram.  Please read suratyl Kahf (the Cave), where the 7 sleepers (pious believers ) had a guard dog companion.  People may mention hadiths against dogs, but the Quran supercedes any hadith.

Also, the word for dog in arabic is 'kelb', almost the same as the word for heart; 'qalb'.  Allah sbwt does everything for a reason.  You cannot find a more loyal creature than a dog.  The dog, kelb, is the gold standard of the loyalty and devotion metaphorically symbolized by the heart, qalb.

Just as Allah has created mankind to serve and worship Allah, similarly Allah has created animals to serve us.  If only us Muslims can approximate the unflinching loyalty and devotion of the qalb of the kelb.  In other words, our loyalty and devotion to Allah should not be less than that of the dog to its master.

By spreading such falsehoods as dogs being haram, great harm is caused in denying Muslims the benefits of dogs.

That being said, the dog, like the pig, sometimes eats it's own waste or the waste of other dogs.  Unlike pigs, the dog does this sparingly. For this reason, there is a hygiene basis for restricting co-habitation with humans to certain spaces away from where we sleep, perform salat, and eat as described in the hadiths.

Comment: Could you add any references of the word kelb (كلب) and kalb (قلب) being metaphorically related because of It's similarities?